# Why aren't my posts/pages showing up in my WordPress Theme?

Tags: posts, themes, pages

i built a custom wordpress theme, and for some reason don't know why the posts/pages are not showing up in the theme, but they show up in all other themes.  Here is the index.php code:

```
<?php get_header( ); ?>         
<div id = "contentwrapper"> 
<div id = "content" role = "main">
    <div id = "leftcolumn">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?> 
        <div id = "locationimageslider">
        </div>  
        <div id = "locations"> 
            <div class = "location" name = "loc1">
                <p class = "title"> Cafe Coyote </p>
                <p class = "phone"> (619)291-4695 </p>
                <p class = "description"> <span>3:30PM to 6PM:    </span>  $2 tacos, $3 beers & $4 margaritas. </p>
                <div id = "ratings">
                </div> 
                <div id = "imthere">
                </div>  
            </div>  
            <div class = "location" name = "loc1">
                <p class = "title"> Cafe Coyote </p>
                <p class = "phone"> (619)291-4695 </p>
                <p class = "description"> <span>3:30PM to 6PM:    </span>  $2 tacos, $3 beers & $4 margaritas. </p>
                <div id = "ratings">
                </div> 
                <div id = "imthere">
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar( ); ?>
</div>  
</div> 
<?php get_footer( ); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the page.php code:

```
<?php get_header( ); ?>         
<div id = "contentwrapper"> 
<div id = "content" role = "main">
    <?php the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
    <?php get_sidebar( ); ?>
</div>  
</div> 
<?php get_footer( ); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are not showing up where? did you include a template name? are you using the loop in your template? I feel some details are left out. Please try to provide more details about what went wrong and what you've tried and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this basic template layout

```
<?php
    get_header();                           # gets header.php contents

    if (have_posts()):                      # checks if there are any post available for this url
        while(have_posts()):                # starts loop
            the_post();                     # assigns $posts global

            the_title();                    # outputs post title
            the_content();                  # outputs post content
        endwhile;                           # ends loop
    endif;                                  # ends conditional check

    get_footer();                           # gets footer.php contents
```

Answer (score 0):

In both `index.php` and `page.php`, you're calling:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
```

Does your Theme have `content-page.php` or `content.php` files?

(Note: you should probably be using a `content.php` file in `index.php`, and call `get_template_part( 'content' )`.

In `page.php`, you're not calling the Loop properly. You have:

```
<?php the_post(); ?>
```

...instead of:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

That may or may not cause a problem.